# two queries and two inner joins together

Tags: php, sql, inner-join

I have two queries here.
First one shows listings where a cat link = 3.

```
Select * 
  from Listings 
  JOIN Category ON Listings.Category = Category.CategoryID 
 WHERE Link = '3'
```

And the second one shows listing connecting to accounts.

```
SELECT *  
  FROM Listings 
  JOIN Accounts ON Listings.Account_ID = Accounts.Account_ID
```

My try is something like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (Select * 
          from Listings 
          JOIN Category ON Listings.Category = Category.CategoryID 
         WHERE Link = '3') 
  JOIN Accounts ON Listings.Account_ID = Accounts.Account_ID
```

But that doesn't seem to work, any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the error?  Most likely the error is telling you that all tables must have names.  Which means that your subselect that you're doing for a temp table MUST have a table alias.

```
SELECT * FROM (Select * from Listings INNER JOIN Category ON Listings.Category = Category.CategoryID WHERE Link = '3') as T1 INNER JOIN Accounts ON T1.Account_ID=Accounts.Account_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for. I had to change * in the inner query to have all fields (Listings.Listing_ID etc)

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work?

```
SELECT      Listings.*
FROM        Listings
INNER JOIN  Accounts ON Listings.Account_ID = Accounts.Account_ID
INNER JOIN  Category ON Category.CategoryID = Listings.Category
WHERE       Link = '3'
```

You didn't specify which table "Link" is in, so if you use this code (provided it does what you want), I'd recommend that you specify which table the "Link" field is in like so: `WHERE        TableName.Link = '3'`

Comment: The second join condition should be: `ON Category.CategoryID=**Listings**.Category`

Answer (score 2):

The `WHERE ...` should go after the two joins.

You can have `SELECT Listings.*` to show all fields from table Listing, or `SELECT *` to show all fields from all 3 joined tables, or `SELECT Listings.*, Accounts.*` to show from these 2 tables, etc.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Listings l
  INNER JOIN Category c
    ON l.Category = c.CategoryID 
  INNER JOIN Accounts a
    ON l.Account_ID = a.Account_ID
WHERE c.Link = '3'
;
```

Comment: +1: There's no need for the derived table/inline view in the OP's question